# PowerShell command to turn on "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" on a network adapter

Tags: powershell, network-programming

Is there PowerShell command/code to turn on "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" on a network adapter?

I found the following link [How to Turn On or Off File and Printer Sharing in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49753-turn-off-file-printer-sharing-windows-10-a.html) that shows powershell code to turn on "File and Print Sharing" at the firewall (Option 3) but not at the network card (Option 4).

I have found that I can use the file `drfpshare.exe` with the argument `/on` to turn it on.  My preference would be to use straight PowerShell code if possible but if I must use a binary I can make it work.

And the last caveat, the command/code needs to work with PowerShell 2 and above.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Network Adapter Name" -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks"
```

There is also:

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Network Adapter Name" -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks"
```

Comment: This doesn't work in PowerShell 2, though